# How to remove row if grouped value and target value(unique count=1) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Raw Data...

| RefNo | rest1 | Pair | rest2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | A | 11 |
| B | 22 | E | 55 |
| C | 33 | C | 22 |
| C | 33 | F | 66 |
| D | 44 | D | 44 |
| D | 44 | G | 77 |
| D | 44 | H | 88 |

I want to get...

-Groupby: RefNo

-if Value of RefNo = Pair & Unique Count(Pair) = 1 ... remove row

Result...

| RefNo | rest1 | Pair | rest2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 22 | E | 55 |
| C | 33 | C | 22 |
| C | 33 | F | 66 |
| D | 44 | D | 44 |
| D | 44 | G | 77 |
| D | 44 | H | 88 |

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) keeping the rows that are either different for RefNo/Pair or [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) in RefNo:

```
out = df[df['RefNo'].ne(df['Pair']) | df['RefNo'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  RefNo  rest1 Pair  rest2
1     B     22    E     55
2     C     33    C     22
3     C     33    F     66
4     D     44    D     44
5     D     44    G     77
6     D     44    H     88
```

Intermediates:

```
  RefNo  rest1 Pair  rest2  RefNo ≠ Pair  RefNo duplicated  either
0     A     11    A     11         False             False   False
1     B     22    E     55          True             False    True
2     C     33    C     22         False              True    True
3     C     33    F     66          True              True    True
4     D     44    D     44         False              True    True
5     D     44    G     77          True              True    True
6     D     44    H     88          True              True    True
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get your level of logical thinking? Great Senior.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using pandas. Here's the code to remove rows where the unique count of "Pair" within each group of "RefNo" is equal to 1 and "RefNo" is equal to "Pair":

```
import pandas as pd

# Your raw data
data = {
    'RefNo': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'rest1': [11, 22, 33, 33, 44, 44, 44],
    'Pair': ['A', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'G', 'H'],
    'rest2': [11, 55, 22, 66, 44, 77, 88]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by 'RefNo' and filter the groups
filtered_groups = df.groupby('RefNo').filter(lambda x: x['Pair'].nunique() > 1 or x['RefNo'].nunique() > 1)

# Output the result
print(filtered_groups)
```

This code groups the DataFrame by "RefNo" and then filters the groups using the lambda function. The lambda function checks if the unique count of "Pair" within each group is greater than 1 or if the unique count of "RefNo" within each group is greater than 1. If either of these conditions is true, the group is kept in the filtered DataFrame. Otherwise, the group (and its corresponding rows) is removed from the result.

Comment: I want to filter out those which grouped(RefNo) value has 1 unique value of Pair and have the same value.